# Is there a way to add the current day's date within an email body in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Tags: javascript, html, date, mailto

Where I work there is the need to send emails where we need to add a specific code and then the current date on a new line, I have been able to sort out the first aspect using the following:

`<button onclick="location.href='mailto:Kofax.AriesNotes@xxxxbank.co.uk?body=NB%0d%0aHMLR%0d%0a';">HMLR</button>`

On the third line I want the date to pre fill in dd/mm/yyyy format but am having difficulty working out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inlining the event handler, make a separate function (say `buttonClicked`) and attach it to `onclick`. Inside the `buttonClicked` method, use the `Date()` constructor to get a date object. Then using the `getDate()`, `getMonth()`, and `getFullYear()` functions, build a date variable in the format you desire. Afterwards, do a string concatenation to add that to the mailto: URL string, and finally point `location.href` to that.